# Экспорт данных в документ для печати

Tags: php

Имеется стандартная форма ФИО, Должность, Организация, Адрес.
По нажатию кнопки из этой формы попадают в таблицу.
Как проще всего реализовать возможность, что бы по нажатию кнопки введенные данные подставлялись в определенное место в документе для печати?

Пример: Оператор вбивает данные организации и при нажатии на кнопку в папку сохраняется документ, например ворд( или любой другой,  лишь бы было форматирование), где в загруженный шаблон договора дарения уже подставлены введенные значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я для этих целей использую библиотеку свободно распространяемую библиотеку PHPExcel (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). Шаблон готовится, соответственно, в Excel, где для ячеек, куда будут подставляться значения, задаются псевдонимы. Это позволяет не завязывать программу на конкретные адреса ячеек, в результате шаблон очень легко менять.

В тексте программы это выглядит примерно так:

```
$templ_doc = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($template_file_name);
$sheet = $templ_doc->getSheet($sheet_number);
$xls_doc = new PHPExcel();
$xls_doc->addExternalSheet($sheet, 0);
$xls_doc->removeSheetByIndex(1);
$sheet = $xls_doc->getSheet(0);
foreach ($data as $alias => $value)
{
    $sheet->setCellValue($alias, $value);
}
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xls_doc, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save($file_name);
```

По моему опыту, самый простой и гибкий вариант.